# Oidc-client infinite loop when calling signinRedirect

Tags: angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm using angular 8 with oidc-client-js. I'm connected to IdentityServer4 (Code Flow + PKCE). After I open the app (inside main component) I want to check if user is authenticated. That's why I call signinRedirect(). Instead of manually clicking the button I just call it inside the constructor (the whole flow worked when I was just clicking the button to call signinRedirect()). The issue is that I'm stuck inside infinite loop. Angular keeps calling IdenityServer and refreshing login page. The api call to the server (and redirect to login page as a result) works fine but it doesn't stop. Please help.

```js
export class AuthService {
  private userManager: UserManager;
  private user: User;

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
    this.userManager = new UserManager(AuthSettings.settings);
    this.userManager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  checkCredentials() {
    if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      this.redirectToLogin();
    }
  }

  redirectToLogin() {
    return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
  }

  isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }
}
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.checkCredentials();
  }
}
```

The user enter the angular app. Then I call authorize endpoint (signinRedirect, sending server things that are required in code flow) - server checks for the cookie if user is logged in. If not it redirects me to the login page. The issue is that scenario works if I click a button that calls (signinRedirect) but not when I execute it when a component is open. The loops ends with log - Showing login: User is not authenticated. The loop begins with Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration. Then - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5555/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ng&state=kYkvO3CO4SW3asopth-dmZW8SYkuyz79Npfn0K4MPAMCT&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20API&code_challenge=2iGwqANCfZGshjmhDmmwm4Eh4Q8SowgPcImf1-CsDzs&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=kYkvO3CO4SW3asopth-dmZW8SYkuyz79Npfn0K4MPAMCT. Then it repeats.

Comment: isn't the oidc client really old and depricated?  I think theres a new more angular way to do this

Comment: You're probably checking credentials on the login page... Don't do that

Comment: based on your comment on my answer.   You are mixing 2 concepts.  The signing redirect, is NOT redirecting to the login.  Your signing redirect handles completing the challenge, and redirecting after signing, additionally your user is being set in a promise, you need to wait for that to complete before checking checkCredentials or else you may be redirecting before the user is set.

Comment: Yes I know that. But that method is calling an endpoint and a user might be redirected to login page. I can implement a normal redirect in the other way. I apologize, because the title is confusing. I will change that.

Comment: basically what you need to do is 2 things.  1. Create a way to redirect to login, for credential validation.  e.g if the user is trying to access a protected resource redirect them to login.  2.  Then you need to handle the redirect,  configure your redirect url in IdentityServer4 to be another page that allows anonymous. e.g login/access and there you attempt to read the access token infromation from the url using the oidc client,  you can even redirect to the login, but you need to attempt to read the access token information first.

Comment: the access token information is automatically read using one of the methods on the oidc client, I forget which I don't have my old application in front of me

Comment: OK. I get it. But my question is why signinRedirect() method entering the infinite loop. Once called it make a request to GET http://localhost:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration, then to GET http://localhost:5555/connect/authorize and then it repeats. When I call this method via button it stops after the call to /authorize.

Comment: There are still unclear things. So answer these questions and I'll can help you out.  1. Is identity server residing on the same url your application is.  e.g are you integrated with the site or trying to open this in an Iframe/modal.
2. Do you get to the signin page and enter your credentials, if so  are you getting a code back in your server and is your server using it to obtain the access token?

Comment: Just as a guess, you're probably redirecting the code back to your client, instead of requesting an access token from your server

Comment: I mock the login page so it has only the login button (the in controller I use mocked user). Basically all the ui is presented in angular. Instead of using identityserver login page I have a custom one displayed by the angular.

Comment: @johnny5 I edited my question (you can see more details above)

Comment: hmm sounds like a race condition.  When you redirect back to the application, with the user. the AppComponent constuctor executes again before the user manager can set the user. so it kicks you back to the login screen, but you've already logged in, so it sends the same token back etc.

Comment: you can probably fix this by just checking the url to see if it contains the token query params and if it does then don't redirect

Answer (score 2):

maybe I'm late to respond. Here are my observations.

this below code in your auth service constructor works asynchronously,  there is a very good reason you will not have the user object populated by the time check credentials called in-app component, also fixing this by making the constructor is an antipattern, you really need to have an async and await usage here.

```js
 this.userManager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
```